# Change items in list in React when an item has been clicked

Tags: reactjs

I'm quite new to ReactJS and I have trouble understand how different components can communicate with each other.

I do have a component that will render a list and each list item is a different component. I want to keep the components as small as possible.

Now, each list item can have a property named `active` and if the property is set to true, an additional class is added.

This is the class that defines a single item in the component.

See this below code for my component defining a single list item:

```
export default class OfficeRibbonTab extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      active: props.active ? props.active : false
    }

    // Assign all the correct event handlers.
    this.setActive = this.setActive.bind(this);
  }


  setActive() {
    this.setState({active: true});
  }

  render() {
    // When the tab is defined as active, add the "active" class on it.
    if (this.state.active)
    { var tabClassName = "active"; }

    return <li onClick={this.setActive} className={tabClassName}>{this.props.tabName}</li>;
  }
}
```

So, I have propery `active` which is passed to this component, which I store in the components state.
When I click the list item, I set to state of the current item to be active.
The problem is that I want all the other list items to become inactive, thus setting the state of active to false.

The code below is an overview of my list:

```
export default class OfficeRibbon extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    // Call the 'base' constructor.
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    var tabs = [];

    // Loop over all the tab elements and define how the element should be rendered.
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.dataSource.tabs.length; i ++)
    {
      if (i == 1)
      { tabs.push(<OfficeRibbonTab active={true} key={this.props.dataSource.tabs[i].name} tabName={this.props.dataSource.tabs[i].name}></OfficeRibbonTab>); }
      else
      { tabs.push(<OfficeRibbonTab key={this.props.dataSource.tabs[i].name} tabName={this.props.dataSource.tabs[i].name}></OfficeRibbonTab>); }
    }

    return (<div>
      <div className="wrap-top">
        <OfficeRibbonTitle title={this.props.title}/>

        <ul className="tabs">
          {tabs}
        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>);
  }
}
```

It doesn't seem like rocket science, but I want to do it the React way without re-inventing the wheel.

Anyone who can guide me in the right direction?

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `OfficeRibbonTab` manages its own state, which is fine, but it never informs its parent component of the state change. The most common approach would be to supply a callback function to each child component, so that it can then communicate back to the parent:

For example, `OfficeRibbon` will now contain a function `handleTabSelect` that gets passed down as a prop to each `OfficeRibbonTab`. And in `OfficeRibbonTab`, when a tab is clicked, you simply invoke the callback, and pass in the selected tab's index or id:

**OfficeRibbonTab.jsx**

```
 setActive(tabIndex) {
    this.props.handleTabSelect(tabIndex);
 }
```

**OfficeRibbon.jsx**

```
 handleTabSelect(tabIndex) {
    this.setState({activeIndex: tabIndex});
 }
```

Now in `OfficeRibbon`, you update your state to set the `activeIndex` or `activeId`, again either by the index or an identifier of your choosing. By setting state in `OfficeRibbon`, we necessarily force a `render()` of its children. As a result, we simply match the index of the iterator with the `activeIndex` of your state, when we iterate in `render()`:

```
<OfficeRibbonTab active={index === this.state.activeIndex} onClick={this.handleTabSelect} ... />
```

Comment: Thanks, almost ready to accept this answer. One additional thing. What should I change in OfficeRibbonTab to pass the tabIndex to the setActive method?

Comment: I think something along those lines: `return <li onClick={() => this.setActive(0)} className={tabClassName}>{this.props.tabName}</li>;` If not, please advice. I do mark your answer as accepted. Thanks for your support :-)

Comment: Bit more tweaking to my code was necessary but it's working right now. :-)

Comment: Yep, that arrow function will work just fine. And here's another approach: http://codepen.io/mikechabot/pen/yJNEdz?editors=1010

Comment: I've seen rumblings where folks would rather bind a function in the constructor, rather than use arrow functions, since the latter seemingly would create new functions on each render, as oppose to each instantiation. Although, this tends to border on premature optimization for me...I still sprinkle in arrow functions as you did above.